# How to find multiple words on the same line in Notepad++

Tags: regex, file, parsing, notepad++, logging

I have a 4MB log file from the Windows XP firewall which I'm trying to find lines that have both DROP and an IP and a port number. My regex-fu is weak and I'm assuming this is the reason I'm struggling.

The words "DROP", "10.1.1.1" (for example) and "8801" need to be found on the same line and may be spread across the line and separated by one or more other words.

Any help (or suggestions of another method to do this) are much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to find specific IP and port numbers then something like this should do it : DROP.*10\.1\.1\.1.*8801

Comment: @Mike: Are "DROP", IP and port in the order you wrote them or do you need to be able to find any permutation of them?

Comment: Beside the solution of Andy - read this: http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/regExpList.php. It explains the regex syntax for notepad++

Answer (score 6):

The easiest solution should be:

```
DROP.*10.1.1.1.*8801
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do it in notepad++

```
DROP.*10\.1\.1\.1.*8001
```

Or a simple regex for different IPs (as you don't need to validate the IP address itself)

```
DROP.*\d\.\d\.\d\.\d.*8801
```

Comment: Why do you think that he needs the trailing wildcards? IMHO you don't need .* at the start & end.

Comment: @tanascius NP++ is fickle and I misinterpreted my testing, answer amended

Answer (score -1):

It seems notepad++ RegEx does not recognise curly brackets, non-capturing groups or \b. The closest I could find is:
`DROP\s.*[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+.*\s[0-9]+` or
`DROP\s\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.+\d+.*\s\d+`

Comment: It will, you just have to escape them.